# VBA to bring outlook "New Items Alert" window to the Front

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using outlook 2013 in Windows 10. I set up a rule to display a msg in the new item alert window when a new email comes in. Can I bring the "new item alert window" to the front and stay on top of the other applications? or are there any other ways to have a pop up windows staying on top of the other apps when a new email comes? 
Thanks.

Code copied from [https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7][1]

```
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim ReminderWindowHWnd As Variant
On Error Resume Next
ReminderWindowHWnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, "1 Reminder")
SetWindowPos ReminderWindowHWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS

End Sub
```

Comment: Read the last two lines of accepted answer: https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/-net-general/313641-setwindowpos.html

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7. The alert windows is still behind the other apps.